# How can I run asyncio library code on top of Twisted's asyncioreactor?

Tags: interop, twisted, python-asyncio, python-3.6

I've managed to import/install Twisted's `asyncioreactor` and execute a trivial asynchronous function:

```
from twisted.internet import asyncioreactor
asyncioreactor.install()
from twisted.internet import task
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
from twisted.internet.defer import ensureDeferred

async def sleepy(reactor):
    print("SLEEPING")
    await task.deferLater(reactor, 3.0, lambda: None)
    print("done sleep")
    return 42

@task.react
def main(reactor):
    d = ensureDeferred(sleepy(reactor))
    d.addCallback(print)
    return d
```

I'd like to intermix an asyncio library in said code, for instance `asyncio.sleep`.  I've tried the following:

```
from twisted.internet import asyncioreactor
asyncioreactor.install()
from twisted.internet import task
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
from twisted.internet.defer import ensureDeferred

import asyncio

async def sleepy(reactor):
    print("SLEEPING")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("done sleep")
    return 42

@task.react
def main(reactor):
    d = ensureDeferred(sleepy(reactor))
    d.addCallback(print)
    return d
```

which produces the following error:

```
 $ python test.py
SLEEPING
main function encountered error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    @task.react
  File "/Users/blz/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/task.py", line 908, in react
    finished = main(_reactor, *argv)
  File "test.py", line 18, in main
    d = ensureDeferred(sleepy(reactor))
  File "/Users/blz/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 823, in ensureDeferred
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, coro, Deferred())
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/Users/blz/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1301, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "test.py", line 11, in sleepy
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
  File "/Users/blz/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 476, in sleep
    return (yield from future)
builtins.AssertionError: yield from wasn't used with future
```

Fair enough, thought I, so I tried swapping `await asyncio.sleep(3)` with `await ensureDeferred(asyncio.sleep(3))` and `await asyncio.ensure_future(asyncio.sleep(3))`, but I get exactly the same error.

#### How can I schedule an aio coroutine (and/or `Future`) to run on the same event loop as is used by `asyncioreactor`?

Comment: Has there been any further updates to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> so I tried swapping await asyncio.sleep(3) with await
> ensureDeferred(asyncio.sleep(3)) and await
> asyncio.ensure_future(asyncio.sleep(3))

You were almost there, you should combine the two, and use `Deferred.fromFuture` instead of `ensureDeferred`:

```
await Deferred.fromFuture(asyncio.ensure_future(asyncio.sleep(3)))
```

The rule is, `async def` functions running in Twisted context (with `ensureDeferred`) can await only on `Deferred`, and `async def` functions running in asyncio context (with `ensure_future`) only on asyncio `Future` (one can always await on other coroutine objects (results from `async def` function calls), but the chain will ultimately lead to `Deferred/Future`). To convert from asyncio `Future` to `Deferred` use `Deferred.fromFuture` and to convert to asyncio `Future` use `Deferred.asFuture`.

One can switch contexts from one to another and back. In this (contrived) example we start with `sleepy_twisted` run in
Twisted context, which does Twisted sleep, then it switches to asyncio context to run `sleepy_asyncio` which does asyncio sleep, but then switches again to Twisted context for Twisted sleep:

```
from twisted.internet import asyncioreactor, task
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks, ensureDeferred, Deferred
import asyncio
asyncioreactor.install()

async def sleepy_asyncio(reactor):
   print("Sleep 2")
   await asyncio.sleep(1)
   print("Sleep 3")
   await Deferred.asFuture(task.deferLater(reactor, 1, lambda: None), loop=asyncio.get_running_loop())
   
async def sleepy_twisted(reactor):
   print("Sleep 1")
   await task.deferLater(reactor, 1, lambda: None)
   await Deferred.fromFuture(asyncio.ensure_future(sleepy_asyncio(reactor)))
   print("done")

@task.react
def main(reactor):
    return ensureDeferred(sleepy_twisted(reactor))
```

Answer (score 3):

Wow, you've come across an interesting corner case!
By using asyncio.sleep() you have triggered some interesting behavior.

I think you might have uncovered a bug in
Twisted's integration with the Python 3 asyncioreactor and async/await.
You may wish to follow up with the Twisted developer's on the Twisted mailing list.

I'm not 100% sure, but here are my thoughts.

The implementation of asyncio.sleep() is tightly coupled to the Python 3
asyncio implementation.  It uses the asyncio.Future (which is similar to Twisted's deferred), and it uses get_event_loop() (which is similar to Twisted's reactor).

asyncio.sleep is implemented like this:

```
@coroutine
def sleep(delay, result=None, *, loop=None):
    """Coroutine that completes after a given time (in seconds)."""
    if delay == 0:
        yield
        return result

    if loop is None:
        loop = events.get_event_loop()
    future = loop.create_future()
    h = future._loop.call_later(delay,
                                futures._set_result_unless_cancelled,
                                future, result)
    try:
        return (yield from future)
    finally:
        h.cancel()
```

I changed your code example slightly to pass Twisted's
asyncioreactor event loop into asyncio.sleep():

```
from twisted.internet import asyncioreactor
asyncioreactor.install()
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet import task
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
from twisted.internet.defer import ensureDeferred

import asyncio

async def sleepy(reactor):
    print("SLEEPING")
    await asyncio.sleep(3, loop=reactor._asyncioEventloop)
    print("done sleep")
    return 42

@task.react
def main(reactor):
    d = ensureDeferred(sleepy(reactor))
    d.addCallback(print)
    return d
```

I still got the same error as you: **builtins.AssertionError: yield from wasn't used with future**

The stack trace looks like:

```
main function encountered error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 16, in <module>
    @task.react
  File "/Users/crodrigues/twisted8/src/twisted/internet/task.py", line 908, in react
    finished = main(_reactor, *argv)
  File "b.py", line 19, in main
    d = ensureDeferred(sleepy(reactor))
  File "/Users/crodrigues/twisted8/src/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 823, in ensureDeferred
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, coro, Deferred())
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/Users/crodrigues/twisted8/src/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1301, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "b.py", line 12, in sleepy
    await asyncio.sleep(3, loop=reactor._asyncioEventloop)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 478, in sleep
    return (yield from future)
builtins.AssertionError: yield from wasn't used with future
```

I think the asyncio.sleep() is a coroutine that is supposed to run to completion
on the asyncio loop, but this is not happening here, hence the assertion.

I think the problem is being introduced by **result = g.send(result)**.
I'm not sure you can **send()** to a coroutine like this and expect it to work.

I advise you to ask on the Twisted mailing list to get more detailed feedback.